# How do I add a specific element to the DOM in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface, view, ember.js

For styling purposes, I'd like to create a div that acts as an overlay when a different div is being hovered on.

I planned on using a custom event to capture `MouseIn` and `MouseOut` on one element.

And then create the div before every other section to act as an overlay, showing them as out -of-focus.

Essentially, in my template, I have

```
{{#each answers}}
    {{render "simpleSearchAnswer" this}}
{{/each}}
```

And that sub-view template thingie is:

```
<li class="questioncontainer">
    <div {{action "select" this}} class="questiontile">
        <div class="row questiontitle">
            <p><span>{{title}}</span>
            <i class="icon-info-circled"></i></p>
        </div>
        <div class="row questiondescription">
            <p><span>{{description}}</span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

I'd like to add a new div at the top to act as the overlay, like

```
<li class="questioncontainer">
    <!-- NEW STUFF BELOW-->
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <!-- NEW STUFF ABOVE -->

    <div {{action "select" this}} class="questiontile">
        ....
```

But after rendering, not before, while the user is working with the application.

I guess, essentially what I'm asking is, is it possible to add a div using Ember.js dynamically?  After rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a custom view for "simpleSearchAnswer", define the methods MouseEnter and MouseLeave and then just use JQuery to accomplish what you need to happen.

Something like:

```
App.SimpleSearchAnswerView = Em.View.extend({

    mouseEnter: function (){
        //jquery to add your div
    }),

    mouseLeave: function (){
        //jquery to remove your div
    })

});
```

You can access the Jquery object of your view using `this.$()`

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html has a list of all the events you can use under "Event Names".